# Triggering a function inside a dynamic element

Tags: jquery

I'm using a script that basically converts a select box into a rating system. All good until I placed the element inside a SweetAlert modal.

The issue is the element's script isn't triggering as the HTML is within a dynamic element, created after the DOM has loaded.

I've read it's something to do with delegation but I'm struggling to understand how to do this in practice - I had the same issue with ChosenJS plugin so if anyone's worked with this they might be able to advise?

Thanks in advance,
G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can you want to select an element that is loaded and then delegate down to the item. For example

```
$("body").on("click", "div#element", function(){
    alert("this is working!");
});
```

The body is always loaded so we can target that, then search for a div with an id of element. This will fire when the div with id of element is clicked no matter when it is loaded.